# (Mutable)LiveData is not getting observed on UI

Tags: android, android-livedata

I went threw plenty of similar posts on SO, but still I was not able to find the reason why I am not able to observe the `LiveData` on the UI.

I am working on a project for learning purposes. What I am trying to do is to fetch a value from my `Room`database and display it on the UI. For the sake of clearness, I am showing only the relevant code snippets.

**Dao.kt**

```
@Query("SELECT maxValue FROM DoItAgainEntity WHERE id = :id")
    fun getMaxValue(id: Int): LiveData<Int>
```

**Repository.kt**

```
override fun getMaxValue(activityId: Int) = doItAgainDao.getMaxValue(activityId)
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
private val mMaxValue = MutableLiveData<Int>()

override fun getMaxValue(id: Int): LiveData<Int> =
   Transformations.switchMap(mMaxValue) {
            repository.getMaxValue(id)
   }
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
viewModel.getMaxValue(activitiesAdapter.activities[position].id)

viewModel.getMaxValue(activitiesAdapter.activities[position].id).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
     // THIS CODE IS NEVER CALLED
     Log.d("getMaxValueObserver",it.toString())
}
```

How can I reach the `Int` value provided in the `LiveData` object? I know, this is almost a newbie question, but could you please explain me what I am missunderstanding?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's because you do a switchMap on `mMaxValue`, which never changes a value (at least from your sample). You could just do `fun getMaxValue(id: Int): LiveData<Int> = repository.getMaxValue(id)`. As I see you do not need the `private val mMaxValue = MutableLiveData<Int>()` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of steps that needed to be done to make this code working. Many thanks to @ChristianB for solving this problem. These were his suggestions:

1. If the `Entity` has more than one column/field, how should `Room` know which value you want when `LiveData<Int>` is returned? So, the whole row (which is definded as an `Entity` object) must be returned instead, this would be the entity where the ID matches the parameter `:id`.

**Dao.kt**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM DoItAgainEntity WHERE id = :id")
 fun getMaxValue(id: Int): LiveData<DoItAgainEntity>
```

2. in the `Repository` you can filter/map for any field you actually need. Or even map it to a complete different (domain) object.

**Repository.kt**

```
override fun getMaxValue(activityId: Int): LiveData<Int> = doItAgainDao.getMaxValue(activityId).map { entity -> entity.maxValue }
```

3. The `switchMap(someLiveData)` gets only called when the value of `someLiveData` changes, and then another `liveData` can be returned from it. But this was not my case. I just wanted to get a value from the `LiveData`, which goes down to my `DAO`. So `switchMap` is not needed here.

**ViewModel.kt**

```
 override fun getMaxValue(id: Int) = repository.getMaxValue(id)
```

4. Finally, observing the `LiveData` on the UI works. The duplicate call to `viewModel.getMaxValue(activitiesAdapter.activities[position].id)` from the original question should be also removed.

**Fragment.kt**

```
viewModel.getMaxValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    // THIS CODE HAS NOW BEEN CALLED :)
    Log.d("getMaxValueObserver",it.toString())
    return@Observer
})
```

5. Last but not least, If the `Entity` was updated like it was in my case, **after creating the DB first, uninstall the app completely, do a proper DB version increase, so `Room` can run a migration on the DB! Clean & Rebuild the Project, Invalidate Caches / Restart.**

Answer (score 1):

You do not get your LiveData updated because you do `switchMap` on `mMaxValue`. But that LiveData never changes (as I can see from your sample).

You actually do not need the property `private val mMaxValue = MutableLiveData<Int>()`.

You can simplify your function to:

```kotlin
fun getMaxValue(id: Int): LiveData<Int> = repository.getMaxValue(id)
```

### SwitchMap

- [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#switchMap(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20androidx.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E))

> Returns a LiveData mapped from the input source LiveData by applying switchMapFunction to each value set on source.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I also tried this approach as well, however I'm still not able to run the code in the `Observer`.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you mean you can not compile your code? What is the error?

Comment: The code compiles without any errors. The issue is that the `Log.d("getMaxValueObserver",it.toString())` line from the `Observer` never gets called.

Comment: Could it be that your `SELECT maxValue FROM DoItAgainEntity WHERE id = :id` never returns any value? You could do a quick test in your repository: `override fun getMaxValue(activityId: Int) = MutableLiveData(42)`. Then you should get `42` in your Fragment.

Comment: unfortunately it seems to me that the answer of all questions is definetly not 42 :). In other words, this didn't change anything on the behaviour. But thanks for this awesome test :).

Comment: Well your observation of the LiveData looks correct. Where do you call `viewModel.getMaxValue()` from your Fragment? I recommend you create some Default LiveData like I showed you above in your ViewModel, once you can observe this and get a value you move it down to the Repository, and if that is working you can go further to your DAO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227205/discussion-between-christianb-and-bwappsandmore).

Comment: as @ChristianB pointed, everything seems to be perfect and I have a quick question, is your table name`DoItAgainEntity`?

Comment: @ChristianB I've posted an answer based on all of the suggestions/solutions that you provided to help solving the problem. Thank you so much for explaining such essential things to me. It blew me away and helps me to grow as a developer. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewModel

```
val mMaxValue = MutableLiveData<Int>()
override fun getMaxValue(id: Int){
    repository.getMaxValue(id).observeForEver{it ->
       mMaxValue.value = it
    }
}
```

And in the Activity or Fragment :

```
viewModel.getMaxValue(activitiesAdapter.activities[position].id)

viewModel.mMaxValue.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    // THIS CODE IS NEVER CALLED
    Log.d("getMaxValueObserver",it.toString())
}
```

Comment: It is not a good idea doing the observation of the LiveData in the ViewModel using `observeForever` and map it to another LiveData. There are mapping functions for this! The observation should happen in the Fragment/Activity.